# How can I show items by categoryId on a dynamic page using Next.js, Prisma, and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

Show Items by CategoryId on Dynamic Page (nextjs, prisma, typescript)

Hello, I think I have almost everything, but I don't really know how to show items by categoryId on dynamic page. I have these parts of code:

**Prisma model >>**

```
model Item {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug       String
  title      String
  about      String
  category   Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId Int
  img_path   String
}

model Category {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug     String
  title    String
  items    Item[]
  img_path String
}
```

**Func to get items by category (thanks Nurul) >>**

```
export async function getCategoryById(id: number) {
  try {
    const category = await prisma.category.findUnique({
      where: { id },
      include: {
        items: true,
      },
    });
    return { category };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}
```

**Block where I link to the [category] page >>**

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import CategoryBlock from './CategoryBlock';
import { getCategories, getCategoryById } from '@/prisma/categories';

const CategoryPage = async () => {
  const { categoriesFound } = await getCategories();

  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col gap-10 w-full">
      <p className="font-medium text-3xl">Категории</p>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-x-5 gap-y-10 w-full">
        {categoriesFound?.map((category) => {
          return (
            <Link href={`/catalog/${category.id}`} key={category.id}>
              <CategoryBlock
                src={`/category/${category.img_path}.png`}
                alt={category.title}
                title={category.title}
              />
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default CategoryPage;
```

**[category] Page itself (need to do something here) >>**

```
const ItemsListByCategory = () => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen mt-40 container">ItemsListByCategory</div>
  );
};
export default ItemsListByCategory;
```

Important note that Items should be on *server-side* I think (maybe I'm wrong)...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.